# UITextfield Text not showing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Creted the username Textfield

```
    txt_Username = new UITextField{
    Placeholder = "Enter username.",
    BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None,
    VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center,
    AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No,
    AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None,
    ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing,
    Background = TextFieldBackground,
    LeftView = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0,8, 8)),
    LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always,
    ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next,
    ShouldReturn = delegate {
        txt_Password.BecomeFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    }
```

// Created the login Button

```
    btn_Login = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.Custom);
    btn_Login.SetTitle ("Login", UIControlState.Normal);
    btn_Login.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("/login_btn.png").CreateResizableImage (new UIEdgeInsets (8, 8, 8, 8)), UIControlState.Normal);

    btn_Login.TouchUpInside += delegate {
        Login ();
    };
```

added to ViewController.

```
View.addSubview(txt_Username);
View.addSubview(btn_Login);
```

Button Action Calling method `Login()`.

```
   void Login (){   
      Console.WriteLine ("TEXTPASSWORD",txt_Username.Text);
    }
```

End Result at console Its prints only `TEXTPASSWORD` the value in side txt_Username is not showing.

UITextField.Text is not showing any value.

Let me know what i have done wrong.

@All 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Isn't `Console.WriteLine` like this acting like a String.Format? In which case, you need `Console.WriteLine ("TEXTPASSWORD {0}",txt_Username.Text);`

Comment: Is placeholder text is visible?

Comment: @kiran Did that solve your problem? If so, I will add an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine ("TEXTPASSWORD {0}",txt_Username.Text.toString());
```

.toString() could work to get the text you need printed

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `Console.WriteLine`. You are giving the method 2 parameters, instead of appending a string to be shown in the console.

```
Console.WriteLine ("TEXTPASSWORD" + txt_Username.Text);
```

Keep in mind, that the placeholder is not text. What I mean by that is, if `txt_Username` is empty, and then use `txt_Username.Text`, nothing will show, since `.Text` is null or empty ("").

If you want TEXTPASSWORD and `txt_Username.Text` on two different lines, you should use the return format for strings

```
Console.WriteLine ("TEXTPASSWORD\r\n" + txt_Username.Text);
```